# Double value that is NaN output as a string as "nan"

Tags: java, c++, c, linux

I have a C/C++ application that writes numeric values into redis as a string. I also have a Java application that will read these values out of redis. On occasion for valid reasons, we end up with a floating-point value that has a value of `NaN` or `-NaN`. However, when using `sprintf(charPtr, "%e", dblVal);`, the value is output as `nan`. I also tried the same statement with `%E`, and it resulted in `NAN`. When Java attempts to parse via `Float.parseFloat()` or `Double.parseDouble` it throws a NumberFormatException.

This application has been ported from Solaris to Linux and subsequently gone through some Linux upgrades and at some point "NaN" became "nan". I can't say for certain on what upgrade ultimately introduced this behavior.

I have gone through an excercise utilizing cmath's `std::isfinite()` and `std::isnan()` and can ultimately define my own valid `(-)NaN` or `(-)Infinity` strings, but this doesn't seem like I need to be reinventing normalized NaN and Infinity strings. Infinity may be a bit different as the C side outputs `inf` yet Java wants `Infinity`.

Ultimately I need to be able to decode data written by the C++ app in Java. nan and inf cannot be decoded by Java as written. My focus was on NaN, but Infinity is a case that should be covered.

Comment: Interesting NaN info, yet what is the question/goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use something like this in your java code for parsing a double?

```java
double parseDouble(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
  try {
    return Double.valueOf(s);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("nan")) {
      return Double.NaN;
    } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("inf") || s.equalsIgnoreCase("+inf")) {
      return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("-inf")) {
      return Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    } else {
      throw e; // Invalid string
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that seems like a reasonable case, since it would only be checked in the event of a bad parse in the first place, thus we wouldn't be checking for every valid parse. I'll wait a little while to see if anyone has anything else to say on the matter.

Comment: It might be worth tracking down what other libcs use for those values (I think the Windows CRT uses something like `1.#QNAN`?) and accounting for them too.

Comment: The functionality of how we are passing floating-point has been bothering me for a while. Basically I’m at the mercy of how it’s been implemented in the languages and I don’t see changes coming to accommodate either side. Your answer covers my question given that Java and libc are just different. That said, I think handling the format on the C side of things would potentially be more efficient as I’d be doing binary comparison via isnan and isfinite as opposed to string comparisons in Java, but on Java the comparison would only occur if parsing fails first.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux case is (a) correct behaviour according to [ISO/IEC 9899:2001](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8):

> [`%e`, `%E`]
>
> [...] A `double` argument representing an infinity or NaN is converted in the style of an `f` or `F` conversion specifier.

and the text for

> A double argument representing an infinity is converted in one of the styles `[-]inf` or `[-]infinity` -- which style is implementation-defined. A double argument representing a NaN is converted in one of the styles `[-]nan` or `[-]nan(n-char-sequence)` -- which style, and the meaning of any n-char-sequence, is implementation-defined. The F conversion specifier produces `INF`, `INFINITY`, or `NAN` instead of `inf`, `infinity`, or `nan`, respectively.277)

I.e. the safest in Java would be to try to parse the double, and if that fails, lowercase the `String` and test the existence of `-` as the first character and the remainder after the possible sign with  `.startsWith("nan")` and `.startsWith("inf")`

Of course this doesn't help if you need to support the non-standards-conforming Windows C runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

A potentially more universal option would be to convert the floating-point number into hex when written to redis and then converted back when read. This would ensure that there wouldn't be any precision loss by converting it to a decimal string, but also cover the +/-Inf and NaN cases.

This is possible since both sides are using IEEE floating-point numbers.